# Data save is checksum recommended

Tags: java, android, security, serialization, checksum

I want to save data to Android internal storage in binary format. Data has values from [android.location.Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) too and a lot of others. I will not use `writeObject`, because that save a lot of unnecessary information, but I will save field by field value, (maybe some data even truncated) as `putLong` `putDouble` to a byte array and so on.

To the internal storage I will save myDataObject by myDataObject with appending method, when new data available, eg location updates

I want to be preventive and know if a data is lost, modified and now is invalid and detect the part which is wrong to minimize the loss.

Thats why I am thinking to write at the final of my byte array a checksum ( hash) of that data.

Is recommended to write that one? I know the SHA crypto takes a lot of processor speed, which I don't want. What method is fast enough for this? - count number of bytes with 1 for eg?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only worried about random storage corruption on small amounts of data (a few KBs), then [CRC32](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) is a good fit. It's fast and will be highly likely to detect random corruption.

If you're worried about malicious modification (implied by the security tag), that's a whole different question.